# How to tell if O_DIRECT is in use?

Tags: io, linux-kernel

I'm running an IO intensive process that supports O_DIRECT. Is there a way to tell if O_DIRECT is being used while the process is running?

I tried "`iostat -x 1`" but I'm not sure which field would help me.

Thanks.

Comment: What means are you looking for?  While the IO is being done?  When the file is opened?

Comment: While IO is being done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to get the pid of the running process. Once you get the pid, you can do

```
cat /proc/[pid]/fdinfo/<fd number>
```

You will aslo have to know the fd number of the file being opened.

It will show flags field. The flags field is octal value displaying the flags passed to open the file descriptor fd. You will have to examine it to know whether `O_DIRECT` is set or not.

As an example, on my ubuntu machine(X86_64), I created 2 files - foo1 & foo2

```
touch foo1 foo2
```

and then opened foo1 with `O_DIRECT` and foo2 without `O_DIRECT`. Below is the program

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%u\n", getpid());

    int fd1 = open("foo1", O_RDWR|O_DIRECT);   //O_DIRECT set

    printf("foo1: %d\n", fd1);
    int fd2 = open("foo2", O_RDWR);         //Normal
    printf("foo2: %d\n", fd2);
    sleep(60);
    close(fd1);
    close(fd2);
    return 0;
}
```

On running this I got the output:

```
8885
foo1: 3         //O_DIRECT
foo2: 4
8885 is the pid. So I did

cat /proc/8885/fdinfo/3     //O_DIRECT
pos:    0
flags:  0140002
mnt_id: 29 
-------------------------------
cat /proc/8885/fdinfo/4
pos:    0
flags:  0100002
mnt_id: 29
```

From the above output you can see that for `O_DIRECT`, in the flags field `0040000` is also set.